# what is time complexity of 2 for loop written in one loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, time-complexity

Hi i was just thinking if i write for loop like given below , what will be time complexity of it. it will o(n^2) or just o(n)

```
for(var i=0,j=0;i<arr1.length || j<arr2.length;i++,j++)
{
    //some code here
}
```

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: i think its o(n) only but i was not sure if i was correct

Comment: When you write it like that, it doesn't translate to a nested loop which means , execution-wise,  that for every item in array A you execute/consume every item in array B for that iteration. This  means you get a number of executions equals to A times B. What you wrote just processes /executes two items at a time, one from A other from B, you can think of it as consuming from both arrays at the sime time. So complexity is the minor of the sizes of arrays. Either O(A) or O(B) but essentially it is O(n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming there are no further loops in the `//some code here`, the time complexity is `O(N)`, because the loop breaks as soon as both `i<arr1.length` and `j<arr2.length`, and both `i` and `j` are incremented on every iteration. It will run for `Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length)` iterations.

For

```
i<arr1.length || j<arr2.length
```

to be `false` (and hence no more iterations), there needs to be

```
i >= arr1.length
// and
j >= arr2.length
```

Comment: I think it will run for `Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length)`, since as long as one of the `i`/`j`s did not finish, the condition is `true`.

Comment: thanks interviewer made me little bit confused but i gave the o(n) answer so its right thanks for clearing.

Answer (score 6):

The time complexity is ***O(max(m, n))*** with *m* and *n* the size of `arr1` and `arr2` respectively.

In your `for` loop you increment both `i` and `j` after a loop. The `for` loop stops if both `i >= arr1.length` and `j >= arr2.length`. Since `i` and `j` always have the same value (except for the moment between increment `i` and `j`), it thus ends if both `i` and `j` have reached the end of their corresponding list.

We here make the assumption that incrementing `i` and `j` runs in constant time (well for very large numbers, that will take *O(b)* with *b* the number of bits of a number with arbitrary size), and that the *body* of the `for` loop only contains instructions that run in constant time as well.